# image_tag url path missing digest (md5 fingerprint) - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, view

First, I need `config.assets.compile = false` set to false because of memory issues on Heroku. I am running Puma and Rails 4.  Heroku precompiles my assets on deploy.  I deleted any `manifest.yml` file I may have had.

## view

```
<%= image_tag("folder/image.jpeg", :class => "img-circle") %>
```

In the above view code, the images are not found after deploy.  It looks like the url lacks the md5 fingerprint.  What would cause this?

## SERVER ERROR

```
2017-01-13T17:33:09.701064+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/images/folder/image.jpeg" for 207.181.195.223 at 2017-01-13 17:33:09 +0000
2017-01-13T17:33:09.704165+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-01-13T17:33:09.704167+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/folder/image.jpeg"):
```

## public folder

```
~/public/assets/folder/image-4d35fa2c3d19fe134fe1d8692ea5de0f373117c440371d15a45134f69a252447f4b36.jpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in the file names.

`image.jpeg` needed to be changed to `image.jpg`

The manifest file creates `.jpg` files, so by having `.jpeg` files, it never finds it and can not make the fingerprint.